# update duplicate record based on lowest value in another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains two fields: sequential_id, product_id and is_original, duplicate_products

There are duplicate records with the same product_id (user added same product).

What I'm trying to do is populate the "is_original" column with a 0 or 1, based on the lowest sequential_id, as well as populating "duplicate_products" with the duplicate sequential_id for the MASTER record (essentially where is_original = 1)

Example output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
sequential_id   product_id   is_original   duplicate_products
--------------------------------------------------------------
1                 123            1               3;6
2                 453            1               5
3                 123            0   
4                 332            1 
5                 453            0
6                 123            0
```

At the moment I'm working on a separate solution using Redis and C# to determine the dupes etc. But It would be great if this can be done using SQL queries

I've tried the following but I get an error "too many locks"

```
UPDATE tblproducts AS p 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(sequential_id) sequential_id, product_id 
FROM tblProducts GROUP BY product_id HAVING count(*) > 1) as m 
ON p.sequential_id = m.sequential_id SET p.is_original = '1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a join of the table with the grouped results:

```
update tblproducts t
inner join (
  select 
    product_id, 
    min(sequential_id) sequential_id,
    concat(';', group_concat(sequential_id separator ';'), ';') dups
  from tblproducts
  group by product_id
) g on g.product_id = t.product_id
set 
  t.is_original = (t.sequential_id = g.sequential_id),
  t.duplicate_products = nullif(case
    when t.sequential_id = g.sequential_id then 
      trim(';' from replace(g.dups, concat(';', g.sequential_id, ';'), ''))
  end, '');
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3K6V7RRSpj9krSRPkcMy3y/1).
Results:

```
| sequential_id | product_id | is_original | duplicate_products |
| ------------- | ---------- | ----------- | ------------------ |
| 1             | 123        | 1           | 3;6                |
| 2             | 453        | 1           | 5                  |
| 3             | 123        | 0           |                    |
| 4             | 332        | 1           |                    |
| 5             | 453        | 0           |                    |
| 6             | 123        | 0           |                    |
```

Comment: I've edited the code to suit my needs and I get "Row 1026 was cut by group_concat. My database has 50 million records, could that be the reason?

Comment: This code works for the requirement and sample data you posted in your question. If your actual table and data are not like the ones you posted of course it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To update is_original to 1 or zero based on the lowest use

update Test set  Test.isoriginal_id=5 where sequential_id in(select sequential_id from (select  sequential_id  from Test  group by product_id ) as tab);